# The data does not change in the fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

```
public class DictionariesFragment extends Fragment implements OnDataPass {
    private static final String TAG = "fragmentLog";
    private String nameDictionary;
    private boolean isCreatedFirstDic;
    private TextView textView;

    String data;

    @Override
    public void onDataPass(String data) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onDataPass");
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dictionaries, container, false);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateView");
        if(data != null){
            Log.d(TAG, data);
        }else {
            Log.d(TAG, "null");
        }
        return rootView;
    }

    private class Dictionary {
        String name;
        int wordCount;

        String[] words;
        String[] wordsTranslate;
    }
}
```

Changing the values of variables in onDataPass (this is the interface), they are not saved in the rest of the code, despite the fact that the variable is global. The on Data Pass method is called earlier than onCreateView, but still the data is not saved. I need to take data from onDataPass and use it in onCreateView. How can I do this?

In the code, I added a log entry, from which I realized that first on Data Pass is called, then onCreateView, but nevertheless the time is equal to null. There is data in the on Data Pass method itself, but if you change them, the changes are saved only in it.

Interface:

```
package com.example.dictionaryapp;

public interface OnDataPass {
    void onDataPass(String data);
}
```

In activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_new_dictionary);

    //Creation
    DictionariesFragment dictionaryFragment = new DictionariesFragment();
    dataPasser = (OnDataPass) dictionaryFragment;

    ImageView btnBack = findViewById(R.id.btn_back);
    btnBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            changeActivityBack();
        }
    });
    EditText editTextName = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_name);
    ImageButton btnOK = findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
    btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(editTextName.getText().toString())){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Введите название", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                //Broadcast
                dictionaryName = editTextName.getText().toString();
                dictionaryFragment.onDataPass(dictionaryName);
                changeActivityBack();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please see here the preferred ways to communicate with fragments: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/communicate

Comment: You are not attaching the fragment to the activity, so `onCreateView` would never be called.

Answer (score 0):

> Changing the values of variables in onDataPass (this is the interface), they are not saved in the rest of the code, despite the fact that the variable is global.

The variable is not global - it's a property on the fragment instance with package-private visibility.

> The on Data Pass method is called earlier than onCreateView,

How do you know that? Show the code.

> I need to take data from onDataPass and use it in onCreateView. How can I do this?

Pass in the data you need when you create the fragment.

See: https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create#add-programmatic

> If your fragment requires some initial data, arguments can be passed to your fragment by providing a Bundle in the call to FragmentTransaction.add(),

---

> There is data in the on Data Pass method itself, but if you change them, the changes are saved only in it.

I don't understand what you mean by this.

Comment: Speaking of a global variable, I meant String data. That is, it is visible in both on Data Pass and onCreateView.
 I didn't quite understand what you mean by showing the code, but here is a log entry, with a sequence of execution:
fragmentLog: onDataPass
fragmentLog: onCreateView
The variable changes in onDataPass, but does not change in onCreateView:
fragmentLog: onDataPass
fragmentLog: Text // variable in onDataPass
fragmentLog: onCreateView
/fragmentLog: null // same variable, but in onCreateView

Comment: What code have you written that passes the string? That calls onData? That creates the fragment? Show that in your question.

Comment: Added the activation code and interface